# React - Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I can't seem to figure why I'm seeing the following error - well, what it actually means:

I have this query I'm making with `react-apollo`

```
import { GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID } from '../queries/GetSubscription';
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo';

const { loading: loadingSub, error: errorSub, data: dataSub } = useQuery(GET_SUBSCRIPTION_BY_ID)
console.log(loadingSub) //I see true printed, then false

if (loadingSub === false) {
   return <Spinner />
}
```

So if its in a loading state - I just want the spinner to appear and not to worry about the rest of the code in the component. However I don't feel this actually happens hence I could the error - I guess the code is continuing.

Additionally in the console I see the following:

```
   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useReducer                 useReducer
4. useRef                     useRef
5. useRef                     useRef
6. useEffect                  useEffect
7. useEffect                  useEffect
8. undefined                  useEffect
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I guess that step 8 is where the problem is? But what is that undefined?

Could someone please confirm and how I can resolve.

Thanks.

Comment: Hooks work "magically" based on the order they are executed in the component. A limitation of this is that a component must always run every hook i.e. a hook cannot be hidden behind a condition. So if you have 3 hooks then an early exit render on your component followed by another hook the early exit render will break this rule and cause the warning as sometimes the 4th hook will not run.

Comment: That's very helpful - wasn't aware of that - thanks. So does this mean if I placed that if loading condition, show the spinner, closer to the end, it should be safe? In other words after all my `useState()`

Comment: Yes, you would need to make sure that it is after all of your hooks in that component. From the console log that was posted it appears to be a `useEffect` that is getting skipped in the initial render that is then run in a later render,